# Responsive sliders and jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using a responsive slider from http://responsiveslides.com but it is using ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js and now i have install a left side slide menu for mobiles but it´s using ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js and does two things conflict. The responsive slider wont work with the new jquery version. I have tried not to display them when they shouldnt be used.

What shall to do?

Comment: Can you maybe edit your question with the JS console errors you're getting with the new jQuery? If possible, supply a link to a test site.

Comment: Why don't use stay with lower version then?

Comment: I downloaded the demo and replaced the jQuery with 2.1.1 and it works fine.

Comment: Ok you were right. But to get the mobile menu working should I have the <script> tag at the bottom of my page and then my slider stops. It probably dont work because I also have the same <script> tag in the header, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including both 1.8.3 and 2.1.1 just include the latest one.

I have tried it with the demo provided and it works 100%

Comment: Ok you were right. But to get the mobile menu working should I have the <script> tag at the bottom of my page and then my slider stops. It probably dont work because I also have the same <script> tag in the header, how do I fix it?

Comment: am a fool, it works. Thanks for the help